# synchronization between PL sql developer to sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, plsqldeveloper

I'd be happy if someone could help me.
I need to get data from  PL  sql developer oracle and import of sql server, I want to do automatic synchronization.
now I am exporting an Excel file from PL sql developer oracle, and load  the file into sql server

Comment: We will be happy to help! What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I want to know what's the best way to do this?
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The tool specifically built for this is Sql Server Integration Services (SSIS).  You can create a data flow with source component using Oracle Driver and destination using Sql Server.  You can even add transforms between the two to handle formatting and other tasks.

Here is a link to a series of videos on the topic.  There is plenty of non - video materials as well if you prefer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgB7zdyH0uI